# Pressure profile for a fluid carrying pipe

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

[image]
This is the diagram drawn for analysis of laminar flow in a pipe. While I understood that pressure difference is the main reason behind the flow, I can't understand how two cross-sections in flowing fluid can have different pressures? Since we must have same pressure at all point at same altitude. Can I get help finding the missing piece?